# Merge blocked: fast-forward merge is not possible. To merge this request, first rebase locally

Tags: git, merge, gitlab

I'm working on two branches and they have an open pull request to the `develop` branch.

My two branches are:

1. `test-increase-test-coverage`
2. `feat-add-daily-mileage`

I got this error when I wanted to merge them with `develop` branch:
`Merge blocked: fast-forward merge is not possible. To merge this request, first rebase locally.`

These two branches had conflicts so I rebased `test-increase-test-coverage` branch with `feat-add-daily-mileage` branch with these commands:

```
git checkout test-increase-test-coverage
git fetch feat-add-daily-mileage
git rebase origin/feat-add-daily-mileage

# Then I fixed conflicts and commited

git rebase --continue
git push -f origin test-increase-test-coverage
```

These branches no longer have any conflicts and when I run this command `git rebase origin/feat-add-daily-mileage` again I get this message:
`Current branch test-increase-test-coverage is up to date.`

But I still see this error message `Merge blocked: fast-forward merge is not possible. To merge this request, first rebase locally.` in Gitlab.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> got this error when I wanted to merge them with develop branch

You might need to rebase them locally on top of `origin/develop` first.
Then your merge would be a fast-forward one.

You need to do so for one branch, `test-increase-test-coverage` for instance. And merge it to develop.

Then you do the same for the other branch `feat-add-daily-mileage`  (after a fetch, to get the newly updated `origin/develop`)

Answer (score 0):

In Gitlab, go to your project's Settings->Merge Requests. Under **Merge method**, select `Merge commit` instead of `Fast-forward merge`.
There's a link there explaining the difference as well: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/merge_requests/methods/index.html